# interop excel gives null on worksheet when excel is opened by program

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I am not able to access excel `Worksheet` when excel is opened by program (automation). It gives `System.NullReferenceException`

Works fine when excel is saved and I open it manually and run the below code.

```
Excel.Application excel;
            excel = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") as Excel.Application;
            Excel.Workbook WB;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet;

            xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;  //error line

            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            ...
            ...
```

Note that this line `excel = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal..` passes debugging even when excel is opened by program. Error comes at line marked "error line" in above code

How can I make above code work when excel is opened by program

**EDIT:** below is the scenario for more clarity

- Clicking a button in AUT , which opens up excel sheet
- When excel opens up ,  sheet is visible on screen
- I need to access this sheet programmatically and validate some information

Comment: when I run the above code after opening excel through automaton  `Worksheet` is not recognized .   The above code works fine when I manually save and open excel. But I need above code to be working when excel is opened through my automation. I am clicking an export button in AUT to open excel.

Comment: You haven't opened a workbook, so it's possible that there is no active workbook, from which there cannot be an active sheet.

Comment: I tried this `excel.ActiveWorkbook;` but receiving null on `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: makes sense if you've opened an instance of Excel without any workbooks. you need to open a workbook or ensure that one is already open, otherwise null exceptions to be expected

Comment: The code provided in the question will not "open Excel" - it can only work if Excel is already running. If you think Excel is not running when this code is run then probably there's an instance running in the Task Manager that was not correctly released. And that would explain the behavior described. Please provide a [mcve] that also includes the code to *quit / release* the Excel application. In that case we can tell much better.

Comment: @Cindy Meister  I am not trying to open excel through this code. I am only trying to access excel when it is opened by another program. What I explained above is , when excel is opened by  another program the code above gives me null on error line. When excel sheet is saved and opened manually , it works fine. I need to make it run fine when excel is opened by another program.

Comment: As you can see from the various attempts to help you, things aren't quite clear. So, another program has opened Excel. What opens or creates the Workbook that you're trying to access using `ActiveWorkbook`? Is the Excel application visible so that you can *see* this workbook? If not, try `excel.Visible = true; ` Are you able to save the workbook then as a user? (Note: this is not a suggested solution, but a *test* to see if saving works in the UI or if there's a different problem.)

Comment: `What opens or creates the Workbook` - Clicking a button in AUT  opens up excel sheet.  
  `Is the Excel application visible so that you can see this workbook?` - Yes 
`Are you able to save the workbook then as a user?` - I am able to save workbook manually but not programmatically  . When I save manually and I run the above code on manually saved workbook , it works fine.  Either I need to save it programmatically and then access or be able to access it unsaved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having issues because excel processes were running from previous sessions. When above code tried to connect to excel sheet , opened by another program,  it gave me `null` exception.
 The resolve is to end all excel processes before running above code. 
Somehow , it did not complain when I was running code on manually saved excel. I am not sure why that behavior but for now it is resolved.

Comment: The reason is likely due to how Office applications work with the ROT. They register only *one* instance (the first started) in the ROT. So `GetActiveObject` picks up only that instance. A "left-over" instance was probably registered in the ROT, which is why the code was picking that up instead of the one you expected - and the workbook was not open, there. When automating Office applications it's *very* important to release the objects correctly in order to avoid this kind of thing.